# Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'

Tags: android-studio

I run the app I get the following error. Anybody help.

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'. Task with path 'dexDebug' not found
>   in project ':app'.

Comment: post your buid.gradle file

Comment: Same error here, any solution?

Comment: hi actually the problem is android studio2.0 plz backward statble version and test it.

Answer (score 4):

You can have this error if you're using an old version of Crashlytics gradle plugin.
Check that in your build.gradle (in the app folder), the top most line is :

```
buildscript {
    /*...*/
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Ideally, please check what is the latest version and set it there (instead of a dynamic one which makes Gradle a bit slower on resolution).

Comment: Contrary to the answer, fixed version should be used according to Crashlytics documentation _// We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin_ source: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

In place of **1.+** use the [latest version](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin) of Fabric Gradle Plugin -

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

you should use this way -

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.1'
    }
```

your problem will be resolved for sure.
**Happy coding !!**